# YAML expression for an empty symbol

Tags: ruby, yaml, symbols, string

When I try a round trip to and from YAML on an empty symbol, it changes into a different thing:

```
require "yaml"
YAML.load(:"".to_yaml) # => ":"
```

1. Is this a bug, or intended?
2. What is the correct way to express an empty symbol in YAML? The `yaml` gem gives the following:

   ```
   :"".to_yaml # => "--- ! ':'\n"
   ```

   Is this correct? (If so, it means there is something wrong on the way back from YAML to Ruby. If not, it means there is something wrong from Ruby to YAML.)

Round trip succeeds with strings or non-empty symbols:

```
YAML.load("".to_yaml)  # => ""
YAML.load("a".to_yaml) # => "a"
YAML.load(:a.to_yaml)  # => :a
```

---

**Update**

I just reported this as a bug to [Ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9873).

Comment: It might be a bug? (Comment because I'm not sure), But playing around with things using the yaml gem: 
`YAML.load("--- :'' \n") # => :""`

Comment: That means YAML to Ruby is working correctly, but Ruby to YAML is not.

Comment: Be careful using symbols in YAML, because they're not supported by other languages. YAML is supposed to be portable, so I think that what you're running into is a Ruby-specific corner case, one that I'd hesitate to exercise.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks, I will keep that in mind. But Ruby should choose to either return an error, convert it into a string with warning, or do it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what "correctly" would be, as symbols aren't supported at all. I agree that Ruby should flag it as an error for portability reasons, with, perhaps, with an option that allows non-portable extensions such as symbols, to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to express an empty symbol in YAML is `!ruby/symbol` , with a space after "symbol".

```
YAML.load "!ruby/symbol "
# => :""
```

Comment: This is probably the correct way to handle it, since the `!ruby/symbol` is YAML's way of handling language specific, or non-portable, data-types. At least then it's the responsibility of both the generating side, and the parsing side, to agree on how it should be handled. In code we've written, I specified that Ruby specific data objects had to be coerced to hashes or strings, to maintain portability, which side-stepped the problem. I do use some symbols in YAML we know won't be accessed by any other languages, but those are rare.